# No caller has been set

Tags: ink, testing, unit-tests

I write tests for my smart contract and got this error:

> no caller has been set

The error comes from: `ink_engine-4.2.0/src/ext.rs:325:14`. In function that I want to write tests I have following line:

```
let caller = self.env().caller();
```

Any suggestion what I do wrongly?

I look at the place the error comes from, and I see following code:

```
/// Returns the address of the caller.
pub fn caller(&self, output: &mut &mut [u8]) {
    let caller = self
        .exec_context
        .caller
        .as_ref()
        .expect("no caller has been set")
        .as_bytes();
    set_output(output, caller);
}
```

Comment: [here](https://paritytech.github.io/ink/ink_env/test/index.html#functions) are the function needed while writing test in ink! smart contract. You need to `set_caller` like [this](https://paritytech.github.io/ink/ink_env/test/fn.set_caller.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is not ideal solution, but working.

```
let _accounts = ink_env::test::default_accounts::<ink_env::DefaultEnvironment>();
let contract_addr: AccountId = AccountId::from([0xFF as u8; 32]);
ink_env::test::set_caller::<ink_env::DefaultEnvironment>(_accounts.alice);
```